How to download source to VSCode?
Salesforce Noob here. I used sf cli to create a new project, created some custom objects in my scratch, and now I am trying to download the source from the scratch. I am using sf project retrieve start --source-dir source/formulaforce/ --target-org myDevOrg to try to retrieve, but I am having no luck -  it says nothing retrieved. What am I doing wrong?

The value that you're passing to --source-dir looks to be non-standard, and maybe that's messing things up? The default directory structure usually looks like [project folder]/force-app. Deviations from that generally mean that you'd need to adjust the sfdx-project.json file. If you haven't added your /source/formulaforce directory to sfdx-project.json, maybe the command would work if you use --source-dir force-app in your command instead?

Thanks @DerekF. Yes. I modified sfdx-project.json to reflect the change in the directory. I am trying to follow a tutorial. Hence, the change in dir structure.

Did you modify sfdx-project.json before or after I added my comment? Are you still encountering the issue? Giving us a link to the tutorial you're following would probably be helpful (maybe it's out of date?)

@DerekF I had already modified the sfdx-project.json. It's from a book titled "Salesforce Platform Enterprise Architecture". It was published in 2023 and it's already out of date :)
